# Login as Anonymous User in Keycloak

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak, openid, openid-connect

I am using Keycloak 11.0.0 to secure my Asp.Net Core 3.1 Application.

I am looking for a way to allow users to access certain resources without the need of an own account.
Which resources can be accessed without an account should be configured in Keycloak. Currently we are using a simple role based system.

My idea was to add an `Login with Anonymous User` Button next to the Login Form in Keycloak. This anonymous user is a normal Keycloak user to which i can assign roles.

How can this be done in Keycloak? I think I might need to write an extension, but I do not know which interface i need to implement for this functionality.

Or is there even a better way to accomplish my goal?