# How to enable "Anonymous" Users with RBAC in KeyCloak?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

Currently, I have an role-based access enabled on my back-end. It's similar to @[ch4mp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619830/ch4mp)'s tutorials on [GitHub](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-resource-server). It's a very basic resource server (also a BFF, but that's not the matter) with `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`! That does it's job just fine.

However, now I'm looking to enable some sort of "anonymous" user - similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63389940/login-as-anonymous-user-in-keycloak) or [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6807) *(and many more)*.

An "anonymous" user is granted some basic access to SOME endpoints. Furthermore, I want to save data attributes to said user (e.g. I got a tracking class which requires a factual role). Or like in most front-ends a user can also use the app and interact with it *(and  thus **is required access** to some endpoints)* on a rudimentary level. Further endpoints would require the user to be signed-in!

**How can one implement this with a basic Role-Based Authentication? Preferably with KeyCloak?**

Comment: + the better "question" is - how can I allow this anonymous user to interact with the application? Problem is for a given role I have attributes like ("email") to verify it's authenticity. An anonymous user is *anonymous* and just browsing? Should I identify them via IP?